# issue with substring indexing

Tags: javascript, substring

Instructions for this kata:

In this Kata, we will check if a string contains consecutive letters as they appear in the English alphabet and if each letter occurs only once.

It seems that my code is indexing the strings differently per function call on this one.  for example, on the first test "abcd", the starting index is shown as 0, which is correct, and on the second example, "himjlk", the

```
 var subString = alphabet.substring(startIndex, length);
```

returns "g", instead of "h"

troubleshooting this section

```
var length = orderedString.length;
  //startChar for string comparison
  var startChar = orderedString.charAt(0);
  //find index in aphabet of first character in orderedString.
  var startIndex = alphabet.indexOf(startChar);
  //create substring of alphabet with start index of orderedString and //orderedString.length
  var subString = alphabet.substring(startIndex, length);
```

```js
function solve(s) {
  //alphabet string to check against
  const alphabet = `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`;
  //check s against alphabet
  //empty array to order input string
  var ordered = [];
  //iterate through alphabet, checking against s
  //and reorder input string to be alphabetized
  for (var z in alphabet) {
    var charToCheck = alphabet[z];
    for (var i in s) {
      if (charToCheck === s[i]) {
        ordered.push(s[i]);
      }
      //break out of loop if lengths are the same
      if (ordered.length === s.length) {
        break;
      }
    }
    if (ordered.length === s.length) {
      break;
    }
  }
  //join array back into string
  var orderedString = ordered.join(``);
  //length for future alphabet substring for comparison
  var length = orderedString.length;
  //startChar for string comparison
  var startChar = orderedString.charAt(0);
  //find index in aphabet of first character in orderedString.
  var startIndex = alphabet.indexOf(startChar);
  //create substring of alphabet with start index of orderedString and orderedString.length
  var subString = alphabet.substring(startIndex, length);

  //return if the two are a match
  return subString == orderedString ? true : false;
}

console.log(solve("abdc")); //expected `true`
console.log(solve("himjlk")); // expected `true`
```

`console.log(solve("abdc"));` should provide the substring "abcd" and return true, which it does.

`console.log(solve("himjlk"));` should put together "hijklm" and return `true`, but instead gives me `g` based on index 6 of alphabet, not sure why it's doing this, should be index 7 "h" returns false based upon this error.

Comment: Can you please link to kata?

Comment: Code errors non-withstanding, should not the second one solve for false? himjlk is not in alphabetic order. I would expect solve to return false for it.

Comment: If you want to check if the characters are in alphabetical order and the characters don't repeat, you could do:  `[...new Set([...s].sort())].join('') === s`

Comment: @HBlackorby the function just checks if subString and orderedArray are the same and returns true/false accordingly - not if the input string is ordered yet.

Comment: @obscure yes that is what it does, but the whole point of that function from what I see is to see if the input string is alphabetically ordered. If the two strings match, then they are alphabetically ordered. If not, the input string is not alphabetically ordered (according to his own function description)

Comment: https://www.codewars.com/kata/consecutive-letters/train/javascript is the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're using **substring()** instead of **substr()**. Though that might sound similar there's a difference.

With substring the second parameter doesn't determine the length as you might have expected. It's actually the index to stop.
That your function works as expected with the string abcd is pure coincidence since in this case the length from index 0 and the end index are the same.

```js
function solve(s){
  const alphabet = `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`;
  var ordered = [];
  for(var z in alphabet){
    var charToCheck = alphabet[z];
    for(var i in s){
      if(charToCheck === s[i]){
        ordered.push(s[i]); 
      }
      if(ordered.length === s.length){ break; }
    }
    if(ordered.length === s.length){ break; }
  }
  var orderedString = ordered.join(``);
  var length = orderedString.length;
  var startChar = orderedString.charAt(0);
  var startIndex = alphabet.indexOf(startChar);
  var subString = alphabet.substr(startIndex, length);

  return subString == orderedString ? true: false;
}

console.log(solve("himjlk"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You approach is also correct. I am giving another solution using `sort()` and `charCodeAt`. Instead of getting the index and then breaking string into parts to compare just use `includes()`

```js
function check(str){
  let org = [...Array(26)].map((x,i) => String.fromCharCode(i + 97)).join('');
  str = str.split('').sort((a, b) => a.charCodeAt(0) - b.charCodeAt(0)).join('');
  return org.includes(str);
}
console.log(check("abdc"))//true
console.log(check("himjlk"));//true

console.log(check("himjlkp"));//false
```

## Explanation:

#### Frist Line:

```
let org = [...Array(26)].map((x,i) => String.fromCharCode(i + 97)).join('');
```

is use to create string "abcd....xyz".

- `[...Array(26)]` will create an array of 26(no of alphabets) `undefined` values.
- `map()` is a function which takes a callback and the create an array based the values of previous. The first parameter of `map()` callback `x` is the value itself which will be `undefined`(because all the values in array are undefined).
- `i` the second parameter will be the index of the element. Which will start from `0` upto `25`.
- `String.fromCharCode` is function which takes a character code(integer) and then convert it to string. For example character code for `a`  is `97` so `String.fromCharCode(97)` will return `"a"`. `98` for `"b"`, `99` for `"c"` etc.
- So after `map()` an array like `["a","b"....,"z"]` will be generated.
  -`join()` will convert that to string

#### Second Line:

- `str` is given string. `str.split('')` will convert string to array. For example
  if `str` is `"abdc"` it will return `["a","b","d","c"]`
- `sort()` is the array method which takes the callback. The two parameters are two values to be compared during `sort()`. `a` and `b` are two values.
- `charCodeAt` acts in reverse as `String.fromCharCode`. For example `"a".charCodeAt(0)` will be return `97` for `"b"` it will `98` and so on.
- `a.charCodeAt(0) - b.charCodeAt(0)` which is returned from `sort()` will `sort` array is ascending order. And `join()` will convert array to string.
- So string `"abdc"` will become `"abcd"`

#### Third Line:

The third line is the main one. `org` is string `"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"`. Now if any string is a substring of this string then it means its in alphabetical order. So we check the sorted `str` is includes in the string or not.

You can clean up the second line by

```
str = str.split('').sort().join('');
```

Because if no callback is passed to `sort()` it will sort in default order. Mean alphabetical order.

Comment: The default `sort` algorithm would sort characters in alphabetical order; `str = str.split('').sort().join('');` works just as well.

Comment: haha thank you, a little advanced for me but I'll revisit when the time comes :)

Comment: @DBN I don't think its too advanced. I have added a detailed explanation to the code about each part. Check it. It will surely help you.